# Using "we" in a discussion

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In a discussion with my customer, sometimes I want to mention "we"(means our team), sometimes I want to mention "we"(my customer and I).

What can I use in this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using "you and I" to refer to your customer and yourself, and reserve "we" to mean your team.

Conversely, you could use "we" to refer to your customer and yourself, and "my team" to refer to your team.

Use whichever way you think best implies that you are *on your customer's side*.

Answer (score 0):

Use context.

> Customer: You guys have put together a nice shop.
>
> Anhtu: Thank you.  We try our best.
>
> Customer: Could you help me move this heavy box?
>
> Anhtu: Sure thing.  We should turn it before heading to the door.

These two uses of "we" mean different groups of people.  Why? Because before each "we" different groups of people were mentioned.  That's what provides context.

If the group of people you wish to refer to has not just been mentioned then you should name them explicitly.

Comment: How about Customer:  Why is the service team so incompetent and why do I keep coming back here?  Anhtu:  We're idiots?

Comment: It was intended to point out that we feel that context can often be an unreliable guide to meaning.

Comment: I agree with deadrat. Sometimes the context isn't clear, mentions to both groups. I have to use my team and I, ...

Comment: There are no infallible guides to meaning, but there are plenty of reliable ones, else we couldn't communicate.  But maybe I *should* name the people explicitly.  And maybe the OP should as well.  He's apparently not sure from the context of his conversations, which is why I figure he asked.

Comment: @deadrat how's this?